Acer Aspire 5 wirh i7 or Ryzen 7
Looking for recommendations regarding Ubuntu and Acer Aspire 5 laptop - which one works better with Ubuntu 22.04 or above -  Intel i7 or Ryzen 7 (11th or 12th generation)?
Had Dell laptop for years with no issues, but for some strange reason Dell is no longer easly available in my part of the world so I have to switch.

Both should work out of the box.
